# pyautogui перестал правильно работать после переустановки виндовса, то есть в pyautogui работают все команды кроме pg.pixel(123, 123)

Tags: python, pyautogui

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][![Консоль во время выполнения

import pyautogui as pg

print(pg.pixel())

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIMWy.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIMWy.png)

Answer (score 1):

Перестал работать pixel()? Напиши свой))

```
import ctypes

def get_pixel_color(x, y):
    gdi32 = ctypes.windll.gdi32
    user32 = ctypes.windll.user32

    hdc = user32.GetDC(0)
    pixel = gdi32.GetPixel(hdc, x, y)

    r = pixel & 0xFF
    g = (pixel >> 8) & 0xFF
    b = (pixel >> 16) & 0xFF

    user32.ReleaseDC(0, hdc)

    return (r, g, b)

# Пример использования
x, y = 123, 123
color = get_pixel_color(x, y)
print(f"Цвет пикселя ({x}, {y}): RGB{color}")
```

Comment: Ура спасибо я думал уже кранты телеграм боту 400 строк как ни как